# Nested Looping Python

Tags: python, loops, data-structures, nested

I want to print out columns of text and I am trying to do this through for loops. I tried using this:

```
a = 0
while a<58:
    for x in Char[a],Numb[a]:
        print (x)
    a+=2
```

but this prints out the two values on separate lines. Is there any way to print it so it comes out like:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5   ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0
while a<58:
    print Char[a], Numb[a]
    a+=2
```

or if you want, you can add some formatting to make it fixed-width:

```
a = 0
while a<58:
    print '{0:3} {1}'.format(Char[a], Numb[a])
    a+=2
```

and maybe a little cleaner:

```
for a in xrange(0,58,2):
    print '{0:3} {1}'.format(Char[a], Numb[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a `for` loop :

```
>>> import string
>>> for i,j in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase,1) :
...    print j,'\t',i #in python 3 print (j,'\t',i)
... 
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
F   6
G   7
H   8
I   9
J   10
K   11
L   12
M   13
N   14
O   15
P   16
Q   17
R   18
S   19
T   20
U   21
V   22
W   23
X   24
Y   25
Z   26
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

1. Rewriting the while loop as a for loop is nicer and makes it less likely to get an infinite loop.
2. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
3. Unpacking tuples / lists is nice (e.g. `a, b = (1, 2)`)
4. Take a look at [string formatting with Python](http://martin-thoma.com/formatting-strings-python/), especially the [columns section](http://martin-thoma.com/formatting-strings-python/#tocAnchor-1-8). Or simply use `\t` (the ASCII-symbol for tab).

As code, it looks like this:

```
import string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase
digits = string.digits

for a in range(0, min(len(chars), len(digits)), 2):
    for char, digit in zip(chars[a], digits[a]):
        print("{0:>3} {1:>3}".format(char, digit))
```

Formatting options like `{i:>n}` mean:

- `>`: Right align (you don't need it. You can also take `<` or nothing.
- `i`: i-th element of the tuple
- `n`: n columns in total. This is also not necessary.

I usually make something like:

```
import string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase
digits = string.digits

headers = ["chars", "digits"]
sizes = [(len(el) + 2) for el in headers]
formatter = "{0:>" + str(sizes[0]) + "} {1:>" + str(sizes[1]) + "}"

print(formatter.format(*headers))
print("-"*(sum(sizes) + len(sizes)))
for a in range(0, min(len(chars), len(digits)), 2):
    for char, digit in zip(chars[a], digits[a]):
        print(formatter.format(char, digit))
```

which gives

```
  chars   digits
-----------------
      A        0
      C        2
      E        4
      G        6
      I        8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your two lists have data as follows, then the following code will do the trick

```
# for python3
Char=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']    # these lists can have as many elements as you want
Numb=[1,2,3,4,5]

for x,y in zip(Char, Numb):       #zip stops when the shorter list ends
  print (x +" "+ str(y) )
```

**Output**

```
sh-4.2# python3 main.py                                                                                                                                                         
A 1                                                                                                                                                                             
B 2                                                                                                                                                                             
C 3                                                                                                                                                                             
D 4                                                                                                                                                                             
E 5
```